# Flash Navigation in an HTML page....storing states?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, navigation

I have a navigation of my site built in Flash, and now need to remember the state based on which page the user is on.  I familiar with flash animation but not great at this sort of actionscripting.  I am using the Greensock plugin for my animations.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) is a library for deep linking inside a Flash site but you could use it in the same way for just your navigation.